# Convert Rcpp::String from table to int for a mode function

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to get the most frequent value (e.g. mode) from the `IntegerVector`. I can use only the Rcpp sugar functions.

How do I convert the output from `String` to `int`?

My code:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
String pier(NumericVector x) {
  IntegerVector wyniki;
  int max;  
  wyniki = Rcpp::table(x);
  max = which_max(wyniki);
  CharacterVector wynik_nazwy = wyniki.attr("names");
  String wynik = wynik_nazwy[max];
  return wynik;  
}

/***R
pier(c(3,2,2,2,2,4,4,5))
*/
```

WYNIK:

```
> pier(c(3,2,2,2,2,4,4,5))
[1] "2"
```

It is correct, but I need the numeric value `2` instead of string value `"2"` that I am presently receiving. Furthermore, I need to convert it in Rcpp and *not* after exporting the function to R,

Comment: @G5W this _is_ an _R_-based question as it relies upon the _R_ package _Rcpp_ and deals with _R_ data types. It is _not_ an _Rcpp11_ question however.

Comment: For the R part,  try  `as.numeric(pier(c(3,2,2,2,2,4,4,5)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using C++98, which looks like it is the case since `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]` was not defined, then to convert a string to an integer use the `atoi()` function and the string's [`.c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) function.

e.g.

```
std::string ex = "1";
int res = atoi(ex.c_str());
```

---

To simplify matters, the use of `.c_str()` does not need to be explicit in this case as pointed out by @nrussell. This saves us the need to create an intermediary `std::string` and just simply use what is returned from accessing the `CharacterVector`.

---

Therefore, having said this, we end up with the following:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int pier(NumericVector x) {
    IntegerVector wyniki;
    int max;  
    wyniki = Rcpp::table(x);
    max = which_max(wyniki);
    CharacterVector wynik_nazwy = wyniki.attr("names");
    return atoi( wynik_nazwy[max] );  
}
```

Test:

```
pier(c(3,2,2,2,2,4,4,5))
# [1] 2
class(pier(c(3,2,2,2,2,4,4,5)))
# [1] "integer"
```

Comment: Good answer; you should be able to rely on `operator char*` being called in `std::string wynik(wynik_nazwy[max]);` as an alternative to the explicit `as<std::string>` as well.